# What is the computationally simplest way to universally index the set of simple graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

If given a simple, integer-labeled, but not necessarily connected, graph $G := (V,E)$ consisting of at least one vertex, i.e. $\lvert \rvert V \lvert \rvert \geq 1$, then is there a function to unambiguously assign it a positive integer value like a serial number? What is the simplest (least computationally complex) mapping or function $f:G\mapsto \mathbb N$ from all possible simple $G$ to the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ such that every $\gamma=f(G)$ is a distinct element of the natural humbers $f(G)\in\mathbb N$ for all $G$?

Hint: $f(G)$ need not be surjective with regard to the codomain of positive integers just its image which you could call $\mathbb \Gamma$.

Comment: The constant 0 function.

Comment: Actually that is not allowed, I have clarified the question to eliminate that ambiguity.

Comment: Well then, the computationally simplest function is the identity. That is, since you are discussing algorithmic complexity, the input must be already encoded as a string in a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ in some way. Reinterpret this string as a $|\Sigma|$-adic representation of an integer.

Comment: I think the 'unambiguously' makes this question go from easy to impossible. Assigning each graph a number so that you can recover the graph from the number is easy. Requiring the number to be unique means you have to solve all the graph isomorphism problem. Given two graphs deciding whether they are isomorphic or not is a hard problem in general.

Comment: @quarague You are reading into the question something that is not there. The question says that distinct graphs should get distinct numbers, not that isomorphic graphs should get the same number.

Comment: Write the upper triangle of the adjacency matrix out as a string of $\binom n2$ bits and call it a binary number.  If all labelled graphs are possible, this is optimal in speed and space.

Comment: @Brendan McKay How would your method distinguish between an empty graph of 3 nodes versus 4 nodes? Both would identically map to 0 using your method, despite being distinct graphs.

Comment: @StuartLaForge Brendan McKay's method can be modified by appending a 1 at the beginning of the binary strings, which would resolve your problem.

Comment: What is the "fa.functional-analysis" aspect of the question? I suggest to remove it as misleading.

Comment: @ChristianGaetz Ok your patch along with Brendan's basic logic would be the meat of a basic existence proof but that has been done to death. I was hoping somebody would actually offer up an actual constructive proof. But no matter, I already have one of my own, but I just wanted to see if anybody was interested in it before I posted it.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek, you are correct in that I already have an "alphabet" of sorts to completely describe simple graphs. From what little I know about p-adic numbers, your method would likely work but it is not going to be smaller than Brendan and Christian's method, which is on the order of the Kolmogorov complexity of simple graphs in general.

Comment: My solution with the adjustment of @ChristianGaetz is not an existence proof but a simple explicit algorithm. I can only guess that you want to do something different from what your question asks.

Comment: @Brendan McKay it was not my intention to offend you but you didn't post your methods as an answer and didn't specify a particular method of converting the upper triangle of an adjacency matrix into a bit string. Since there are several ways, two different people using your method could have gotten different bit strings for the same graph. Also I wanted to get the feedback of real mathematicians on my theorems since I am not affiliated with a university and none of my friends understand math. I am sorry if my way of introducing my theorems to the group seemed brash or naive or insulting.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for my abuse of set notation as I am mapping one mathematical object that is not quite a set i.e. graphs to another mathematical object that is not quite a set i.e. sequences. Feel free to comment or correct notation etc.

**Definitions:**

**(1) The triangular-harmonic numbers** $\Theta$ are a monotonic sequence of rational numbers greater than or equal to one defined recursively as follows:

$$\Theta := \bigcup_{\forall k}\{\theta_k \in\mathbb Q\mid \theta_k \geq 1\}\\
\theta_0 = 1\\
\theta_k = \theta_{k-1}+\frac{1}{\lfloor \theta_{k-1}\rfloor} $$
The first few terms of $\Theta$ are:
$$\left\{1,2,2+\frac{1}{2},3,3+\frac{1}{3},3+\frac{2}{3},...\theta_k\right\}$$

I am grateful to Carlo Beenakker for helping me find the closed form of $\Theta$ which is $\theta_k=\frac{T_k^{-1}}{2}+\frac{k}{T_k^{-1}}+\frac{1}{2}$ for $k\geq 1$ where $T_k^{-1}=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is the inverse triangular number function.
https://oeis.org/A002024

**(2) The index function of** $\theta_k$ is found by solving the closed form for $k$:
$$k(\theta_k)=\frac{2\lfloor \theta_k \rfloor \theta_k- \lfloor \theta_k \rfloor^2- \lfloor \theta_k \rfloor}{2}$$

**(3) The edge-value function** $\mathcal E$ is a function that maps the edges of a natural number-labelled graph to the rational numbers as follows:

\begin{equation}
\text{if }\ G=(V,E) \text{ with }\ V=\{1,2,3 ...n\}\Longrightarrow\exists \mathcal E:E\mapsto \mathbb Q\\
\mathcal E(e_{ij})=\frac{j^2+i}{j}=j+\frac{i}{j}\\ \text{ where }\ i<j \text{ and }\ i,j \in V
\end{equation}

**Theorem: The rationally-ordered graph theorem.**

Claim:
If the vertices of a simple graph are uniquely labeled with integers, then the whole graph can be uniquely mapped to a monotonic sequence of 
rational numbers that is a subset of $\Theta$ the triangular-harmonic numbers.

If $V(G)=\{1,2,3 ..., n\} \Rightarrow \exists \text{ sequence } S_k$ of monotonically increasing rational numbers where $S_k<S_{k+1}$ for all $k$ and $ \{S_k\}_{\forall k} \subset \Theta$.

Proof:
Consider building a sequence of complete graphs over n vertices, one vertex at a time, starting with the one-vertex complete graph $K_1$ labeled with the integer 1.
$$\text{Let }\ K_1 = (V,E) = (\{1\},\{\})\\$$
Adding a second vertex and applying the previously defined edge-ordering function $\mathcal E(e_{ij})\mid e_{ij}\in E(K_n)$ over all edges in $K_2$ gives us:

$$K_2 \longmapsto V(K_2) \bigcup_{\forall e_{ij} \in E(K_2)}  \mathcal E(e_{ij})=\left\{1,2,2+\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

$$K_3 \longmapsto V(K_3) \bigcup_{\forall e_{ij} \in E(K_3)} \mathcal E(e_{ij})=\left\{1,2,2+\frac{1}{2},3,3+\frac{1}{3},3+\frac{2}{3}\right\}$$
$$\cdot$$
$$\cdot$$
$$\cdot$$
$$K_n \longmapsto V(K_n) \bigcup_{\forall e_{ij} \in E(K_n)} \mathcal E(e_{ij})=\left\{1,2,2+\frac{1}{2},3,3+\frac{1}{3},3+\frac{2}{3}, … ,n,n+\frac{1}{n}, ..., n+\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right\}$$

Simple inspection shows that $K_n \longmapsto S= \{\theta_k\}_{k=0}^{T_n-1}$ where $T_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ triangular number i.e. $T_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Now consider that all simple graphs of order n are spanning subgraphs of the complete graph of order n and it becomes clear that the rational sequence of any finite simple graph is a finite subsequence of the trianguar-harmonic numbers:

$$\text{If } G_n \in \{\text{simple graphs}\}\text{ and }G_n \subset K_n \Longrightarrow G_n \mapsto S \mid S \subset \Theta\\ \blacksquare$$

**Corollary 1: Index of simple graphs** There exists an index on all simple graphs of order $n$ such that the computational complexity of each of the indices is on the order of $ O(n^2)$ bits.

Proof:
Given a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ of order $n$, one uses the rationally ordered graph theorem to derive a "graph sequence" $S$ of rational numbers such that the integers denote vertices $V = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n \mid v_n \in \mathbb N \}$ while improper fractions denote the edges between them $E=\left\{\frac{v_j^2+v_i}{v_j}\mid v_i < v_j \text{ for }\forall (v_i,v_j) \in E\right\}\text{   }\therefore S(G\mapsto\Theta)=V \cup E$.

Since from the ROG theorem we know that $S \subset \Theta$ we can simply find the index number of graph $G$ by calculating the sum:
$$I(G)=\sum_{\forall i \in S} 2^{k(i)}$$

Therefore for a graph $G_n$ of order $n$ between the limits of an empty graph and a complete graph we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{T_n-1} \leq I(G_n) \leq 2^{T_n}-1$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2=\infty\Longrightarrow O(n^2)$
$$\blacksquare$$